# VB6 list loop not working when list is very long

Tags: list, types, vb6, integer, long-integer

How do I make VB6 List count work for lists with more than 32767 items?

```
for k = 0 to List2.ListCount  - 1
''do stuff
next
```

The above code works great until I have too many items in my list then list count gets all screwing and goes negative.

How can I fix this? Can I make ListCount be a long data type?

Comment: just found out that List2.ListCount - 1 is returning (-21867 )  WTF?

Comment: Dang it's because List2.ListCount - 1 is an integer data type. How can I make it be a long data type? arghh

Comment: What's the point of having more than 32000 items in a list?

Comment: I new someone would ask that. It's part of an app and it can't be helped. The user can choose to dump that much stuff in the list. There is a select "all" as the first index in the list. Please .. I just need it to work. There are reasons beyond what I can explain here.

Comment: How about adding a second listbox - and linking the Select All checkbox so that it will check all items in both, changing the processing loop to go thru both listboxes?

Comment: List is a bucket with specific items filled by ADO query. Clicking on items needs to do stuff. I can't break things into two lists for this reason. It won't match our company hierarchy.

Comment: You could use a ListView in lvwReport mode.

Comment: Annoys me so much that I wrote new instead of knew*. Just had to call that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the VB6 properties are only signed `Integer` the underlying control uses 32 bit integers so you can use the Windows API to manipulate your list:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
Private Const LB_GETCOUNT = &H18B
Private Const LB_GETTEXT = &H189
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim ix As Long
    For ix = 0 To 40000
        List1.AddItem "X" + Format(ix)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim rc As Long
    Dim wp As Long
    Dim lp As Long
    Dim s As String * 1000
    ' Get count of items into rc
    rc = SendMessage(List1.hwnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0)
    ' Get the 39001th item
    rc = SendMessageString(List1.hwnd, LB_GETTEXT, 39000, s)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Having said that switching to a ListView might still be a good idea.